# Django not creating tables " Table django_session does not exist"

Tags: python, mysql, django

Whenever I run `python manage.py migrate` I cannot get the required tables. The only tables that I get are `django_content_type` and `django_migrations`. Because of this I cannot log into the admin page or create a super user. I am using `MySQL-connector-python-rf`, python 3.4 and Django 1.9.8 I have followed instructions of deleting the tables to creating a new database and the problem still persist.

This is my database and apps setup in `settings.py`

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'usermie',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'testerdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    }
}
```

I was using django before and working on a project on this same computer, but now I do not know what has happened and why I am not getting the tables.

Below is what I get when I run `python manage.py migrate`

```
(mie) C:\Users\dane_\DjangoProjects\pagemie>python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'usermie':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Usermie

(mie) C:\Users\dane_\DjangoProjects\pagemie>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:                                                                                                    
Apply all migrations: contenttypes, auth, sessions, admin, usermie                                                    
Running migrations:                                                                                                       
Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):                                                 
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python_rf-2.1.3-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 177, in _execute_wrapper                                                                 
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python_rf-2.1.3-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 515, in execute                                                                               
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python_rf-2.1.3-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query                                                                         
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python_rf-2.1.3-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1050 (42S01): Table 'django_content_type' already exists
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                                   
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()                                                                                                     
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute                                                                                                                            
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv                                                                                                                          
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle                                                                                                                     
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 92, in migrate       
self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)                                     
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)                                  
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 123, in apply       
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 59, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 284, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)                                                                                           
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute            
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)                                                                                       
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python_rf-2.1.3-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 227, in execute
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python_rf-2.1.3-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 180, in _execute_wrapper
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python_rf-2.1.3-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 177, in _execute_wrapper                                                                 
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python_rf-2.1.3-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 515, in execute                                                                               
File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python_rf-2.1.3-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python_rf-2.1.3-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result                                                                  
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Table 'django_content_type' already exists
```

Comment: please post the apps section of your settings.py this error is actually talking about a data error rather than a missing table as in your title

Comment: Thanks for replying sir, I have posted the apps settings.

Comment: Add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS`!

Comment: I have no apps to be installed. However I will make an app for testing purposes and it to see what happens.

Comment: It says: Incorrect datetime value: '2016-07-25 22:45:16.507552+00:00', please let us know what is the value of USE_TZ in your settings.py

Comment: The value is `True`, I have since changed it to `False`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All the tables I should have are here now. This was what I did. I deleted all tables created in the database. I also removed `usermie` from `INSTALLED_APPS`. After that I ran `python manage.py migrate`. I am wondering if changing `USE_TZ` to `False` did anything as I have deleted the tables multiple times in the database before with no success. I also removed `MySQL-connector-python-rf`.

I still get these messages but all seems fine now:

```
(mie) C:\Users\dane_\DjangoProjects\pagemie>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 50, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    using=db)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 192, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\__init__.py", line 126, in create_permissions
    Permission.objects.using(using).bulk_create(perms)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 450, in bulk_create
    self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1056, in _batched_insert
    using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1039, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1059, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1047, in as_sql
    result.append(self.connection.ops.bulk_insert_sql(fields, placeholder_rows))
  File "C:\Users\dane_\DjangoVirtualEnvs\mie\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python_rf-2.1.3-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\mysql\connector\django\operations.py", line 223, in bulk_insert_sql
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'
```

Comment: change function 'bulk_insert_sql' of /site-packages/mysql/connector/django/operations.py to:   return "VALUES " + ", ".join([items_sql] * len(num_values))

Answer (score 1):

MySql does not accept timezone info in the datetime value such as `'2016-07-25 22:45:16.507552+00:00'`, the problem is the `+00:00` part. By default, Django should use naive datetime objects, as you can see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/ so normally this should not be a problem, but it seems that your data contains timezones.
Maybe you could check that USE_TZ is False in your settings.py and then try to run the migration again.

Comment: I changed it to `False` now, however before I changed it to `False` I created an app `usermie` and I see a different error now not involved with timezone.